# Tracing the co ordinates of current location

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I want to trace the latitude and longitude coordinates of the current location..I use tis code to trace it...

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{

      map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,46,320,370)];
            [map setDelegate:self];
            map.showsUserLocation=YES;
            [map setZoomEnabled:YES];
            [self.view addSubview:map];
            [map setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
           [self locationManager:locationManager didUpdateToLocation:newlocation fromLocation:oldlocation];}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)managerdidUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)NewLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)OldLocation
{
     locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"%f %f",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude,locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude);
}
```

But my app crashes
  My log report:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Map locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5863890'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing the location too early. Depending on the actual state of the device, there might not be a location information there yet (as you NSLog is milli- or microconds after the `startUpdatingLocation`). The proper way to get location information is to set a `delegate` on you `locationManager`, e.g. `self` and implement this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
}
```

This way your app will be notified, as soon as there is a known location available.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Map locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5863890'
This is my crash report

Comment: Did you correctly implement the `didUpdateToLocation` method (no typos) in the class `Map`? As you seem to have passed a `Map` object as a delegate, the method needs to be implemented there. Check if it is and if there are no typos in there.

Comment: Good, its still missing the implementation of the delegate method though and if it is in the correct class (i.e. is the delegate method in the same class as above `viewDidLoad` as you used `self` as delegate).

Comment: Oops jst nw noticed,bt still i'm getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement this delegate function ...

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    userLocation=newLocation.coordinate;


    NSLog(@"updated location is %f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude);


}
```

and also implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in your .h

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your viewDidLoad method you are calling didUpdateToLocation. You shouldn't do that. By setting the delegate of the map to be this class, it will call the method when the location is updated.

You also need to add space in the method name

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)managerdidUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)NewLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)OldLocation
```

should be

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)NewLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)OldLocation
```

Comment: But you are still calling the function yourself, which you should not do. Let CoreLocation do that when it has a location ready to give you.

Comment: Thanks for ur rply.... But I tried tat too...Itz nt calling tat delegate..... I don't y???

Comment: Instead of that I used tis delegate too - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation bt still ving same issue